# How to make a powershell script that can check all xml files for a string that gives the location where the node is to be replaced

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I want to make a PowerShell script that can check all XML files in a folder  for a string node called "_inlink", The string then gives the location from the root where the node is to be which the parent of _inlink location wants to have replaced.

Here is an example of the source XML:

```xml
<imgdir name="stand">
  <canvas name="0" width="84" height="88" basedata="longstringofbasedatawewant">
    <vector name="origin" x="47" y="80" />
    <int name="z" value="0" />
    <vector name="head" x="-9" y="-63" />
    <vector name="lt" x="-45" y="-73" />
    <vector name="rb" x="44" y="1" />
  </canvas>
  <canvas name="2" width="1" height="1" basedata="useless">
    <vector name="origin" x="47" y="80" />
    <int name="z" value="0" />
    <vector name="head" x="-9" y="-63" />
    <vector name="lt" x="-45" y="-73" />
    <vector name="rb" x="44" y="1" />
    <string name="_inlink" value="stand/0" />
  </canvas>
```

So I want the "stand/0" of _inlink of the node of the canvas node 2 to tell the script to replace the node "2" (child node of stand) with the entire node of stand/0.
It should be noted the parent node will not always be "stand" it could be anything but the _inlink will always tell us what the node it wants the node of _inlink to be.

Result ending:

```xml
<canvas name="2" width="84" height="88" basedata="longstringofbasedatawewant">
  <vector name="origin" x="47" y="80" />
  <int name="z" value="0" />
  <vector name="head" x="-9" y="-63" />
  <vector name="lt" x="-45" y="-73" />
  <vector name="rb" x="44" y="1" />
</canvas>
```

I've gotten this far and I'm not sure if this even is on the right track

```bsh
$name = "_inlink " 
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\arcane - Part 2" | ForEach-Object {
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $xml.SelectNodes("//canvas[@width='1' and @height='1']") |
        Where-Object {$_.name -eq "$name"} 
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example of source and desired result XML.

Comment: Hopefully this is better.

Comment: Your expected output seems to be exactly the same as as the first `<canvas>` child of `<imgdir>`, except that the value of the `name` attribute of the `<canvas>` parent is changed from `0` to `2`; is that the idea?

Comment: correct Jack Fleeting except the value of the basedata is different which is what is the image

Comment: But in both you have `basedata="longstringofbasedata"`, so where is the difference?

Comment: I have revised the basedata

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to merge 2 `<canvas>` nodes and replace their parent with the merged node if one of them contains a child node with an attribute name that has the value "_inlink"? Which data should be discarded when merging the 2 nodes? What should happen if there is no second node without the `name="_inlink"` attribute? Or more than one?